# Computing surface area of Hyperboloid with $2 \pi \int r(z)dz$ vs using normal vector

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals

I want to compute the surface area of a hyperboloid:

$$ x^2 + y^2 -(z-11)^2 = a$$

For $0 < z < 14$, where $a$ is some positive number such that the hyperboloid is of 1 sheet.

What I did was:

$$ x = r \cos(\theta), y = r \sin(\theta) \Rightarrow r(z) = \sqrt{a+(z-11)^2}$$

And hence, the perimeter of every "ring" of the hyperboloid is:

$$ 2 \pi r(z) $$

Which means that the surface area should be:

$$ \int_{0}^{14} 2\pi r(z)dz =  \int_{0}^{14}2\pi\sqrt{a+(z-11)^2}dz$$

What my friends did was computing:

$$\left | N \right | = \left | \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (r \cos(\theta)) \times \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (r \sin(\theta)) \right | = \left | (-r\cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta),r \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} )) \right | = \sqrt{r^2 + (r \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial z})^2 }$$

And:

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial z} = \frac{z-11}{\sqrt{(z-11)^2 + a}} $$ Which means that: $$ \left | N \right | = \sqrt{a+ 2 (z-11)^2}$$

And hence the surface area should be:

$$ \iint\limits_S 1 \cdot ds =  \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{14}\sqrt{a + 2(z-11)^2}dzd\theta$$

Which naturally, yields a different result.

---

I tend to think that my own way, using $ \int 2\pi r(z)dz$ is wrong. But, It's striking me that the integrands of both ways are so similar, and I can't explain why or what's wrong with my own way.

Comment: When you do the "perimeter of every ring", you are essentially adding up a bunch of straight cylinders to approximate a curved surface. If you ignore the rotation and just look at a slice of the hyperboloid, this is equivalent to the $2$D problem where you try to compute an arc length with only straight horizontal line segments - it doesn't work.

Comment: I tend to disagree. Take for example the integral computation of a circle's perimeter: You take a triangle with an angle $d\theta$, and you conclude that one of it's infinitesimal edges is of length $R \cdot d\theta$, and then you sum all of these edges using an integral and you get $2\pi R$.

Comment: Those are not horizontal line segments.